# Set Pandas Data Frame elements to "" if first column is False

Tags: pandas, set, conditional-statements, dataframe

I have a dataframes:

df0:

```
    A  B  C 
False  y  z
True   n  o
False  i  j
```

How can I set to "" only the elements where THE FIRST COLUMN False?

res:

```
  A    B  C
False  .  .
True   n  o
False  .  .
```

Comment: You say you want to set to `""` only the elements where the first column is True, but your example seems to set elements in rows where the first column is *False* (not True) to `"."` (not `""`) instead.

Comment: When FALSE actually. Thanks for the remark. Now correct

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`df.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing-loc-iloc-and-ix):

```
In [29]: df.loc[~df['A'], ['B', 'C']] = ''

In [30]: df
Out[30]: 
       A  B  C
0  False      
1   True  n  o
2  False      

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

---

Here is how I parsed the table into a DataFrame:

In a file called `data` I saved

```
    A  B  C 
False  y  z
True   n  o
False  i  j
```

and then in the IPython interpreter:

```
In [27]: df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s+')

In [28]: df
Out[28]: 
       A  B  C
0  False  y  z
1   True  n  o
2  False  i  j

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: This is not working, the column A is not an Index. The index is a np.datarange

Comment: Actually, my solution *is* using `A` as a column, not an index. I've added an explanation of how I re-constructed your `df`. If it does not match what you intend, then **post code** which defines `df`.

Comment: I get the following error: AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'loc'", u'occurred at index 2010-12-31 00:00:00'). I have chacked the df type is correct: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>. I am using Python 2.7 (Anaconda)

Comment: I stand by my answer as being correct *given the table you posted*. I invite you to reproduce my steps and see if you get the same result. If you do, then the problem is in a discrepancy between the table you posted and your actual DataFrame (or in some other code you are not showing). That is why it is important for you to post code which reproduces your exact problem.

Comment: @prre72, this error means that somehow, you are accessing `.loc` on a `str` object. figure out how that happens and you'll be good, but you are 100% doing that.

Comment: I have checked again df type is <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> and the first column elements are type <type 'numpy.bool_'>. I really cannot understand why this is not working. What is the meaning of the ~ symbol in front of df?